# How to automatically translate plugin using translate.wordpress.org

Tags: multisite, translation, plugin-wpml, wordpress.org

Is there a way to automatically download translations for a plugin from translate.wordpress.org. I'm testing with WPML String Translation. The plugin has about 20 untranslated strings and I need a translation in 6 different languages. The plugin has translations available on translate.wordpress.org. The plugin owner tells me to go to translate.wordpress.org and get the translation from there manually. Unfortunately, there is no search engine, so I can't find the strings as there are over 20 pages with translated strings. Is there a plugin that can do this automatically, fetch translations from translate.wordpress.org?

Comment: There is a search engine though. Pick a locale first then you can just search in the "Search projects..." box.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know WPML, but if it works like Polylang, It should download the language pack for all plugins installed on your website from translate.wordpress.org.
In translate.wordpress.org, a plugin in a locale must be completed at 90% to be available on your WordPress.

As you're using WPML which is a premium plugin, you should contact their helpdesk as you're paying for it.

Regards